# How do I make another text display after the first one appears in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a mental health website. To make it interactive, I have used a animation text that appears. I was wondering how I can add  another line of text to pass.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

The purple text appears before the black text. I want to add the sentence "We chose mental health  because it matters"

How do I do this?

```css
/* The animation text*/

.intro {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.intro1 {
  animation: showup 7s infinite;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: fuchsia;
}

.intro2 {
  width: 0px;
  animation: reveal 7s infinite;
}

.sub-head {
  margin-left: -355px;
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

@keyframes showup {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  35% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    width: 355px;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 355px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first-box">

  <div class="intro intro1">Welcome!</div>
  <div class="intro intro2">
    <span class="sub-head"> We care about you</span>
    <!-- lol dramatic effect-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to add it where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways:

```js
// set the interval for which the function will run (in our case 7 secons - 7000 )
setInterval(function() {
  // grab all elements with class 'sub-head'
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-head')
  // loop through the found elements 
  elems.forEach(e => {
     // check if the element has a class 'inactive', if there is one, remove it
    if (e.classList.contains('inactive')) e.classList.remove('inactive')
    // if not, add it
    else e.classList.add('inactive');
  });
}, 7000)
```

```css
/* The animation text*/

.intro {
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.intro1 {
  animation: showup 7s ;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: fuchsia;
}

.intro2 {
  width: 0px;
  animation: reveal 7s infinite;
}

.inactive {
  display: none;
}

.sub-head {
  margin-left: -355px;
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

@keyframes showup {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: .8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  35% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    width: 655px;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 655px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first-box">

  <div class="intro intro1">Welcome!</div>
  <div class="intro intro2">
    <span class="sub-head "> We care about you</span>
    <span class="sub-head inactive"> We chose mental health because it matters</span>
    <!-- lol dramatic effect-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am new to js, do you mind adding comments on the js code to describe what the code does?

Comment: I updated answer check now pls (hope you can understand my comnets) ;)

Comment: This code has the exact same functionality as my first interval code and is not any improvement. I cached the elements and use the recommended classList.toggle instead of the inelegant if/else construct you chose.

Comment: Sure mate, you have the point :) , but your first  version was not so elegant and i put best that i can code in between , sorry for that , you may downvote my answer, I upvoted yours, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this -

I test if animation has finished. That is much safer than setTimeout or interval since the animation already has the interval

```js
const elems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.intro2 .sub-head')]
const welcome = document.querySelector('.intro1')
welcome.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  welcome.classList.add('hide')
  elems[0].classList.add("hide")
  elems[1].classList.remove("hide")
});
```

```css
/* The animation text*/

.intro {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.intro1 {
  animation: showup 7s;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: fuchsia;
}

.intro2 {
  width: 0px;
  animation: reveal 7s infinite;
}

.sub-head {
  margin-left: -355px;
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

@keyframes showup {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  35% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    width: 355px;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 355px;
  }
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-box">

  <div class="intro intro1">Welcome!</div>
  <div class="intro intro2">
    <span class="sub-head"> We care about you</span>
    <span class="sub-head hide">We chose mental health because it matters</span>
    <!-- lol dramatic effect-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this is perfect. The only thing I want different is the welcome to not appear in the second part